# Используют ли сессии?

Tags: сессия, php

Используют ли стандартные сессии PHP в высоконагруженных проектах?

Если нет то почему?

Comment: а в своем проекте по результатам профайлинга, Вы уже упираетесь в сессии?

Comment: @good: погуглите сами цитату насчёт premature optimization, хорошо?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используют. Сессии очень несильно грузят, вообще-то.
Другое дело, стоит осознавать для чего вам нужен данный механизм. Не стоит использовать его для долговременного хранения данных десятка миллионов пользователей.

Answer (score 7):

ИМХО РНР такой язык, что вы упретесь в него гораздо раньше, чем в производительность сессий.

Если не хранить в сессиях мегабайты - они работают очень шустро.

Если вам всё ещё беспокойно используйте memcached, а лучше перенесите временную папку, где лежат сессии в [tmpfs](http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/linux/robbins/fs03.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

В высоконагруженных проектах не используют стандартные сессии из-за отсутствия возможности горизонтального масштабирования. Используется альтернативное хранилище сессионных переменных, высокопроизводительное и отказоустойчивое. И дело не в размере сессии, а в количестве обращений на чтение и запись. Во всяком случае не слышал про стандартное хранение сессий в проектах уже от 300 000 хитов в час в прыжке.

Answer (score 0):

Например, у себя реализовал сессии на MySQL. Работает отменно.

Comment: А если дергать надо часто данные из сессии, нормально справляется?

Comment: На странице где нужны сессии - создается два запроса. 
Первый, в самом начале - возвращает данные о текущей сессии. 
Второй, после работы скрипта [`shutdown`][1] - сохраняет измененные данные сессии.
Данные хранятся в JSON-формате.

[1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: ИМХО - база данных слишком тяжелый инструмент для сессий))

Млин. У меня были решения с нагрузкой до 10К/час в пике на одном тазике... Ну млин. Ну на общем фоне к сессиям вообще проблем не было. Задача про 300К в час... Это кластер, или как сейчас модно говорить - горизонтальное облако. Там есть целый ряд вопросов по синхронизации данных и балансе нагрузки. На все сессии хватит одной VDS'ки с парой гиг мозгов и memcache - стандартным иил самодельным. ИД провалидовали, запросили строку, десериарелизовали. Если изменили - записали... Ну делов-то.